# Does my office/lab server need to be providing these services?

Tags: nfs, services, udp, hardening

I'm trying to figure out what services my university Ubuntu 22.04 computer needs to provide to other machines.  I often `ssh` into this machine and other computers in my lab use it as an `NFS` server.  I can't think of any other services the machine needs to provide, however.  As a result, I'm trying to harden the computer by shutting down unnecessary services. Unfortunately given my knowledge of linux services and ports, I'm not sure which are necessary or not.

If I run `$ netstat -A inet --listening`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37725           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:sunrpc          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:nfs             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42757           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:51144         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:17603         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:17600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:12546         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56703           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56607           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:db-lsp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:44911         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:32997         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53815           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55047           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57529           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:sunrpc          0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 localhost:864           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33798           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35842           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36165           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40000           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43526           0.0.0.0:*
```

Because I was recently used to amplify a DNS attack, I've stopped the sunrpc service for the moment.  My understanding is that I need that service as part of NFS (but my understanding could easily be wrong).

1. Based on my needs, which, if any of these services do I need to be providing to other machines.
2. Of those that I do need to provide, besides fail2ban for `ssh` connections, what steps do I need to take to harden my machine?

This may be an overly broad or naive set of questions, if so any insight will still be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you would be better to install a firewall yourself within your lab, especially if the uni has no interest in such things.

Comment: See this [Wikipedia List of Port Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).  Your IT Department is doing you a disservice by not having a "corporate firewall" - A firewall should be in place to protect the entire university, and I do agree with Bib.  If one isn't configured, you should do it on your own.  As a starting point, any port not in the list I gave should **not** be configured to LISTEN

Comment: I agree that you should just configure a firewall and call it a day.  also, technically sunrpc is just used for port lookups, and it's possible to just configure the nfs clients about all the ports it needs for nfs server access, but it's a bit more work.  I would recommend configuring ssh to require privatekey authentication and not just username/password.  also, I would focus on disabling services running on the machines that are not needed.

Comment: It should also be said, that as the uni seems to have no interest in securing their own network, it will only be a matter of time before they are completely compromised. It may also be that this is also the case, just that they do not know about it. One day, they will come in & find their screens asking for bitcoins to unlock all the data.

Comment: Thank you both so much.  I'm still trying to understand things, so excuse my ignorance, but my understanding is that Ubuntu automatically sets up a firewall upon installation.  So when you say "set up a firewall" you are saying to someone like me "better configure the default firewall". Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your first step (along with a firewall) would be to use `netstat -p` to look up which actual services are listening on which ports. Then make your decisions based on the **services**, not on the port numbers.

For example, do you need Dropbox Sync to be running on your server? Your firewall rules shouldn't just be "allow port 8787", they should be "allow 8787 *because* we host Service XYZ which is bound on that port".

You can ignore all sockets that are bound to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`; they are inaccessible from outside anyway, so they might be used for internal process communications.

(Also, do not limit your output to `inet` – you *will* forget IPv6 that way, and you will happen to leave it completely open even as you think you've locked down your IPv4 rules tight.)

> Of those that I do need to provide, besides fail2ban for ssh connections, what steps do I need to take to harden my machine?

At minimum, decide whether each of those services should be "open to the world" or "open to the university" or "open to the lab", and set up your firewall rules accordingly.

For example, the need for fail2ban for SSH would be less if it didn't allow connections from Internet in the first place. (Even if you admin it from home, your university might have a VPN service for that purpose.)

Similarly, NFS with UID-based authentication should be open to the smallest number of "trusted" machines possible (as anyone with root on their own machine can bypass the NFS security) – definitely not to the world – whereas NFS with Kerberos authentication could *almost* be made accessible to Internet (perhaps not wise, but the protocol would be strong enough).

Splitting some services into their own machines (containers, VMs, or physical) is often a good idea.

> Because I was recently used to amplify a DNS attack, I've stopped the sunrpc service for the moment. My understanding is that I need that service as part of NFS (but my understanding could easily be wrong).

"sunrpc" is the Port Mapper service which clients use to look up the dynamic port number, as older NFSv3 versions consist of several different protocols (NFS itself, MOUNT protocol, STATD protocol). It's similar to the MS-RPC port 135 on Windows.

The port mapper is only needed for NFSv2/NFSv3. If you use NFSv4 exclusively, then all you need is the single TCP (not UDP) port 2049.

If you require NFSv3, keep in mind the 'dynamic' part – with a firewall, you will want to manually choose some static port number for each RPC service involved, so that it doesn't change on every reboot. These days they can all be set through the common `/etc/nfs.conf` file.

Comment: You might want to add that the `rpcinfo -p` command can be used to query the local portmapper/sunrpc service to identify the current dynamic port number values. Similarly, `rpcinfo -p <hostname>` can be used to query the portmapper of other hosts. A lab server might also be using NIS servers for centralized management of lab users; NIS would be another set of RPC services (`ypbind`/`ypserv` and possibly other `yp*` services - the naming refers to "Yellow Pages", the old name of NIS) with a possibly dynamic port.